# How to alert when 6 number of spans are created inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code which does create tags based on user input in the input text.
For each input tag - a span will get generated.

```
<div id="tags">
    <span class="tag" id="inptagsAll">Item1</span>
    <input type="text" id="inptags" value="" placeholder="Add 6 items" />
</div>
```

I want to initialize and run a chart using javascript/jquery when 6 tags are input(i.e., 6 spans generated), how to achieve this ?

How to alert when 6 input tags are entered by the user  ?

Comment: So if the user enters a number, you want that many spans created? If they enter 6 you want an alert showing that they entered 6?

Comment: You'll need to add the code that is generating the spans for us to help.

Comment: How to alert() when 6 spans are generated inside the DIV is my question ?.. **not to generate spans when user enters 6** Please read the question, I'm new to jquery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/awhLsp3v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
IF ($("span","#tags").length > 6){
    alert('badguy!');
}
```